# radius of convergence $\sum a_n z^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find radius of convergence of power series $\sum a_n z^n$, where $ a_n $=number of divisors of $ n^{50}$.

I thought of applying root test, but the a_n looks little trickyy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the root test, yet it is best to ignore the specifics of the coefficients and rather use very crude bounds for them (from above and below).
Then you can study the "upper" and "lower" bound, and luckily  both give the same radius.

A reason this works is that when you have sequences $(a_n)_n,(b_n)_n, (c_n)_n$ such that $|b_n| \le |a_n| \le |c_n|$ then 
$$\limsup \sqrt[n]{|b_n|} \le \limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \le \limsup \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}$$

Comment: so i take a_n =1 and find radius, then a_n=n^50 and then again find radius, final result should be min of two?Why should it work this way?

Comment: The first part is correct. You do not take the minimum though; as I said they are equal anyway. I updated the question to make more clear what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Hint; $1\leq a_n\leq n^{50}$. Can you apply the root test to both sides?